# Vertical Axis labels set to middle in Google Visualization Chart

Tags: angularjs, charts, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I am using Google's visualization bubble chart. I need to align the labels in the vertical axis to middle. See the image below please. Something like this. These month names needs to be in between the major gridlines.

[image]

Here is the options I added for this bubble chart, but it does show next to axis line only.

```
var options = {
        sizeAxis: {
            maxSize: 7,
            minSize: 1
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'in',
            startup: true
        },

        fontSize: 10,
        legend: 'none',
        height: 230,
        chartArea: { left: "20%", right: 0, top: 0, width: "70%", height: "200px" },


        bubble: { stroke: '#ffca18', opacity: 1 },
        colors: ['#ffca18', '#ffca18'],
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'none'
        },
        hAxis: {
            ticks: [
                { v: 2015, f: '2015' },
                { v: 2016, f: '2016' },
                { v: 2017, f: '2017' },
                { v: 2018, f: '2018' },
                { v: 2019, f: '2019' },
                { v: 2019, f: '2020' }
            ],

            gridlines: { color: '#dedede' },
            minorGridlines: { color: '#f7f7f7', count: 3 },
            textStyle: { color: '#5f5f5f' }
        },
        vAxis: {
            ticks: [                   
                { v: 1, f: 'May' },
                { v: 2, f: 'April' },
                { v: 3, f: 'March' },
                { v: 4, f: 'February' },
                { v: 5, f: 'January' }
            ],
            gridlines: { color: '#dedede' },
            textStyle: { color: '#5f5f5f' },
            viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
            viewWindow: {
                min: 1,
                max: 7
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: there are no options out of the box for label alignment, but we might can move them manually. will you please share the code used to draw the current chart?

Comment: @WhiteHat I have added the chart options above. Can you help me please?

Comment: @WhiteHat Thank you very much for your help. I will try this today. But in the mean time is ther anything we can make the axis major gridlines extend to outside as shown in the above picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can move the labels manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event,
or in this case, the `'animationfinish'` event, or both.

the chart has a method for `getChartLayoutInterface()`
this returns an object we can use to get the placement of various chart elements.

we can get the placement of the gridlines,
and move the labels in between.

```
function moveYAxisLabels() {
  var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
  var labels = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('text');
  var labelIndex = -1;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
    if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') {
      labelIndex++;
      labelHeight = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#label#' + labelIndex).height;
      labelBottom = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#gridline#' + labelIndex).top;
      labelTop = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#gridline#' + (labelIndex + 1)).top;
      label.setAttribute('y', labelBottom - ((labelBottom - labelTop) / 2) + Math.floor(labelHeight / 2));
    }
  });
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {"label": "id", "type": "string"},
      {"label": "x", "type": "number"},
      {"label": "y", "type": "number"}
    ],
    "rows": [
      {"c":[{"v": ""}, {"v": 2015}, {"v": 1}]},
      {"c":[{"v": ""}, {"v": 2016}, {"v": 2}]},
      {"c":[{"v": ""}, {"v": 2017}, {"v": 3}]},
      {"c":[{"v": ""}, {"v": 2018}, {"v": 4}]},
      {"c":[{"v": ""}, {"v": 2019}, {"v": 5}]},
      {"c":[{"v": ""}, {"v": 2020}, {"v": 6}]}
    ]
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', moveYAxisLabels);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'animationfinish', moveYAxisLabels);

  function moveYAxisLabels() {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var labels = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('text');
    var labelIndex = -1;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') {
        labelIndex++;
        labelHeight = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#label#' + labelIndex).height;
        labelBottom = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#gridline#' + labelIndex).top;
        labelTop = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#gridline#' + (labelIndex + 1)).top;
        label.setAttribute('y', labelBottom - ((labelBottom - labelTop) / 2) + Math.floor(labelHeight / 2));
      }
    });
  }

  var options = {
    sizeAxis: {
      maxSize: 7,
      minSize: 1
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 1500,
      easing: 'in',
      startup: true
    },
    fontSize: 10,
    legend: 'none',
    height: 230,
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 48,
      left: 200,
      right: 18,
      top: 18,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
    },
    bubble: { stroke: '#ffca18', opacity: 1 },
    colors: ['#ffca18', '#ffca18'],
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'none'
    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [
        { v: 2015, f: '2015' },
        { v: 2016, f: '2016' },
        { v: 2017, f: '2017' },
        { v: 2018, f: '2018' },
        { v: 2019, f: '2019' },
        { v: 2020, f: '2020' }
      ],
      gridlines: { color: '#dedede' },
      minorGridlines: { color: '#f7f7f7', count: 3 },
      textStyle: { color: '#5f5f5f' }
    },
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [
        { v: 1, f: 'JUNE' },
        { v: 2, f: 'MAY' },
        { v: 3, f: 'APRIL' },
        { v: 4, f: 'MARCH' },
        { v: 5, f: 'FEBRUARY' },
        { v: 6, f: 'JANUARY' },
        { v: 7, f: '' }
      ],
      gridlines: { color: '#dedede' },
      textStyle: { color: '#5f5f5f' },
      viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 1,
        max: 7
      }
    }
  };

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

the only issue here is the animation,
the chart will move the labels on `'ready'`,
then we move them back on `'animationfinish'`,
so they appear to jump.
you may re-think using animation...

Comment: Sometimes the y-axis labels are missing from the graph, can anyone help me to solve this issue please?